# Como reproduzir som em javascript?

Tags: javascript, meteorjs

Boas, estou a desenvolver um chat, gostaria de saber como adiciono um simples som quando recebo uma notificação.
Estou utilizando Meteor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Penso que poderá ajudar, qualquer duvida, disponha.

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

Ou entao tente utilizar o o Buzz

https://github.com/jaysalvat/buzz/tree/8a42bd42746ac2a78112c9ace4dba9eb7cb29212